# Laravel Lighthouse Problem with schema validation Undefined Scalar Sring

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

**I have installed the packe well , I spent 1 month trying to solve this problem !!please hekp**

Nuwave\Lighthouse\Exceptions\DefinitionException

Lighthouse failed while trying to load a type: string

Make sure the type is present in your schema definition.

at vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/TypeRegistry.php:95
91▕      */
92▕     public function get(string $name): Type
93▕     {
94▕         if (! $this->has($name)) {
➜  95▕             throw new DefinitionException(<<<EOL
96▕ Lighthouse failed while trying to load a type: $name
97▕
98▕ Make sure the type is present in your schema definition.
99▕

```
  +29 vendor frames
```

30  artisan:37

Answer (score 1):

So far I think you have a type with type `string` but it should be `String`. Like:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}
```

Otherwise, please show us your schema.

Comment: Thank you, that’s was helpful ,I doubt in that but did not fix it until you confirmed that to me .